# Nothing happen after click upload excel

Tags: acumatica

i click upload for Excel but nothing happen ?

ScreenId=PM301000 > tab Tasks 
( `Allow upload = true`, 
Graph :

```
[PXImport(typeof(PMTask))]
public PXSelectJoin<PMTask, 
       LeftJoin<PMTaskTotal, On<PMTaskTotal.projectID, Equal<PMTask.projectID>, And<PMTaskTotal.taskID, Equal<PMTask.taskID>>>>,
        Where<PMTask.projectID, Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>>> Tasks;
```

how can i fix it ?﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the primary data view DAC as the PXImport type which for this page is `PMProject`. Change the view entry to the following:

```
[PXImport(typeof(PMProject))]
public PXSelectJoin<PMTask, 
       LeftJoin<PMTaskTotal, On<PMTaskTotal.projectID, Equal<PMTask.projectID>, And<PMTaskTotal.taskID, Equal<PMTask.taskID>>>>,
        Where<PMTask.projectID, Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>>> Tasks;
```